# Hostin Email on Azure

Tags: windows, email, azure, hosting

I'm considering to move my website to a Azure free Website. The problem  is that I want my site to be hosted at "mydomain.com", and also, to use emails like "someone@mydomain.com".

Since I'll have to target my DNS to the Azure server, how can I receive my emails? Is it possible on Azure?

Comment: Your website can be referenced by any domain this is not a problem. I don't really understand what you mean regarding the emails. If you want to host a mail server in Azure you'll probably need a Virtual Machine. You could move your emails to office365.com?

Comment: or get a Google Apps for Business account and point your DNS email records there.

Comment: NOTE - you can't have a custom domain pointed to an Azure FREE website - you have to at least scale up to a shared instance.

Comment: @viperguynaz I got it now. The DNS authority in Brasil (registro.br) doesn't allow me to create DNS records, so I was completely unaware of their existence. All I need to do is to point MX registers for one server and A/CNAME to azure. Thanks for your time, anyway.

Comment: @Fishcake I got it now. The DNS authority in Brasil (registro.br) doesn't allow me to create DNS records, so I was completely unaware of their existence. All I need to do is to point MX registers for one server and A/CNAME to azure. Thanks for your time, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now. The DNS authority in Brasil (registro.br) doesn't allow me to create DNS records, so I was completely unaware of their existence. All I need to do is to point MX registers for one server and A/CNAME to azure. Thanks for your time, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as viperguynaz said, you cannot combine custom-domains and free Azure websites.  You'll want to upgrade your free-tier Azure website to Shared Website Mode

Second of all, just because you're moving your website and it's domain to Azure, it doesn't mean that you should be moving your email to Azure.  Remember, that with domains, you do not need to move all the subdomains underneath mydomain.com together.  You can continue hosting mail.mydomain.com wherever you currently do, right now.  If you need a free/cheap email provider - feel free to use Gmail for business, Office365, or contact any ISP for a custom-domain mailbox.  Those are cheap and plenty.

Comment: I got it now. The DNS authority in Brasil (registro.br) doesn't allow me to create DNS records. So I was completely unaware of their existence. All I need to do is to point MX registers for one server and A/CNAME to azure. Thanks for your time, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As you would have seen the comment responses you need to have a VM and install mail server on it. The point to be noted here is that, you can't attach a custom domain name to Azure Websites and I doubt you can tweek an Azure Website to make it a MailServer.

The other way is to use the SendGrid Service. Azure and SendGrid have come into partnership. There is a freemium version also available. Check out the [SendGrid-Windows Azure](http://sendgrid.com/windowsazure.html), [How to Send Email Using SendGrid with Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/sendgrid-email-service/), [Guest Post: Getting Started with SendGrid on Windows Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/09/10/guest-post-getting-started-with-sendgrid-on-windows-azure.aspx)

Comment: I got it now. The DNS authority in Brasil (registro.br) doesn't allow me to create DNS records. So I was completely unaware of their existence. All I need to do is to point MX registers for one server and A/CNAME to azure. Thanks for your time, anyway.

Comment: I can't recommend SendGrid. Setting up an account took days. SendGrid wouldn't validate our DNS records. Support figure it out only after repeated requests, and recomended to disable default functionalities of our account to bypass the problem. Same story 3 months later when we had to migrate to a separate account due to unreliable integration with Azure Additionally, the .net API is confusing and lacks transparency in many ways. Finally, today is the 3rd day ALL our emails are deferred because of "changes to our infrastructure that MAY throttle SOME of your emails" . We're fully in the mud!